# python 2.7 username with minimum and max

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I am having trouble with this block of code. I just started programming in Python 2.7 and I would like to have some help.

Here is the code:

```
username=raw_input("Please give me a username")
def gebruikersnaam():
    username(len)

    if len(username) >= 8:
        print "Well done"
    elif len(username) <= 1:
        print "More characters please" #Please try again, input your username again.
```

The username must consist of a number too. And I would like to have the user input the username again if the number of characters is 0.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing?  What do you think they mean?  What ways have you attempted to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Basic version

This could be a solution:

```
from __future__ import print_function

while True:
    username = raw_input("Please give me a username: ")
    if not any(c in username for c in '0123456789'):
        print("Username needs to contain at least one number.")
        continue
    if len(username) >= 8:
        print("Well done")
    elif len(username) <= 1:
        print("More characters please.")
        print("Please try again, input your username again.")
        continue
    break
```

Keep asking the user in a `while` loop until you get what you want.

This checks if the user name contains at least one digit:

```
>>> any(c in 'abc' for c in '0123456789')
False
>>> any(c in 'abc1' for c in '0123456789')
True
```

This part is a so-called generator expression:

```
>>> (c in 'abc' for c in '0123456789')
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10aa339e8>
```

The easiest way to visualize what it is doing, is to convert it into a list:

```
>>> list((c in 'abc' for c in '0123456789'))
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>> list((c in 'abc1' for c in '0123456789'))
[False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

It lets `c` run through all elements of `0123456789` i.e. it takes on the values `0`, `1`, ... `9` in turn, and checks if this value is contained in `abc`.

The built-in [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) returns `True` if any element is true:

> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return `False`.

An alternative way to check for a digit in a string would be to use regular expressions. The module [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re) offers this functionality:

```
import re

for value in ['abc', 'abc1']:
    if re.search(r'\d', value):
        print(value, 'contains at least one digit')
    else:
        print(value, 'contains no digit')
```

Prints:

```
abc contains no digit
abc1 contains at least one digit
```

### In a function

You can put this functionality in a function (as requested by the OP in a comment):

```
def ask_user_name():
    while True:
        username = raw_input("Please give me a username: ")
        if not any(c in username for c in '0123456789'):
            print("Username needs to contain at least one number.")
            continue
        if len(username) >= 8:
            print("Well done")
        elif len(username) <= 1:
            print("More characters please.")
            print("Please try again, input your username again.")
            continue
        break
    return username

print(ask_user_name())
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code I must use a def statement. I cant figure it out.

Comment: Thanks alot, you solved my problem. Very easy to read code. Allthough I dont understand the line "if not any(c in username for c in '0123456789'):"

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem. I will add some more explanation about the line with `any`.

Comment: Ok thanks, How would I do that. I cant accept the answer, I dont see a button for it. Where is it located. Btw, I tried your code again. But If I put a a character , say for instance a4, or c4. These print functions would not work: print("More characters please.")
            print("Please try again, input your username again.")

Comment: Did you add `from __future__ import print_function` as the first line in your file?

Comment: `len('c4')` is 2. You need to change your code: `elif len(username) <= 2:` if you want to catch this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re

def check(name):
    if bool(re.search(r'\d', name)) and name != '' and len(name) > 4:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

while True:
    username = raw_input("Please give me a username=>")
    if check(username) == 1:
        print "Username ok"
        break
    else:
         print "Username needs at least 1 digit or too short. Try again"
```

I've managed to cover the case of the space and the username containing at least one digit. I've used regular expressions. Hope that helps somehow!

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks, but the code I must use a def statement. I cant figure it out